# Iterate through a json list in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m looking for a way to iterate through the list so i can display all items in my list. Right now it only displays one saved combination. When i click on the `('.se-saved').click(function()` i get the same combination every time, it doesn’t go to the next item in the list. I'm new to JavaScript. This is what i got so far.

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-btn', function(){        
    var saveDrink = data[num].name;
    var saveFood = input;

    var SaveAll = [];
    SaveAll.push({saveDrink,saveFood});
    var JSONFavorit = JSON.stringify(SaveAll);
    localStorage.setItem("Favorit", JSONFavorit);
    console.log(SaveAll);
    alert("Your fav drink and food combo is now saved");
});         


//runs when btn "Your saved comb" clicks on, the combo.html page
$('.se-saved').click(function(){
    //get from localstorage
    var favoriter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Favorit"));
    console.log(favoriter);
    $("#fave").append("<p> Drink: " + favoriter[0].saveDrink + ". Food: " + favoriter[0].saveFood + ".</p>"); 
});
```

Comment: That's a syntax error! `:P`

Comment: `Object` should have `keys` right ? Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/rnb2dmcw/)

Comment: SaveAll.push({'drink': saveDrink, 'food': saveFood});  Like this?

Comment: this `SaveAll.push({saveDrink,saveFood});` is valid ES6.

Comment: On a side-note, you should try to keep the case consistent in your variable names. Here you mix camelCase (e.g. saveFood) with PascalCase (e.g. SaveAll). The usual in JavaScript is camel case so I would advise sticking with it. If you really favour an alternate casing, you can use it, the main thing is to be consistent.

Comment: Guys, before you start commenting, just asking, could be dumb. Isn't this `}); }); });` part, a syntax error?

Comment: @derby1 See the above comment!

Comment: Where do you set `num`? If it's not going to the next item in the list, the problem is probably that it's not being incremented.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, edit.

Comment: @Barmar im working with a API  thats where the num comes from.

Comment: @derby1 I still think the problem is in that part of your code. If `num` is incremented, then you should be changing the item saved in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! There are some faults in this code. First of all **Object** should be key and value pair. Here you have mentioned it as array. Hence it won't be saved and ended up in error. So you have make sure that it should in following format.

```
SaveAll.push({'drink': saveDrink, 'Food':  saveFood});
```

Note : key name should be enclosed in single quotes.

**Second :** 
You had told that you got same combination every time. Yes! because you have declared the array inside the click function. so every click it will clear previous value in array and it will be new array every time. So bring it out side as follows.

```
var SaveAll = [];
$(document).on('click', '.save-btn', function(){  
// some codes goes here.
});
```

Once you eliminate these error. It will be easy to iterate and get all the values you save in local storage.
[look at this bin.](https://jsbin.com/feyoyo/edit?html,js,output)